# What are the most useful Functional Pearls I should study first?

Tags: design-patterns, haskell, f#, functional-programming, ocaml

Here are the [functional pearls](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Research_papers/Functional_pearls).

From the top of my mind the Zipper pearl is very useful and is used in XMonad and probably many other real-life applications.

Are there any others with similar wide applicability?

Comment: Interesting question, maybe too broad for SO, maybe a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Here are the [haskell idioms](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Category:Idioms), not a functional pearls actually, but a nice list of specific patterns.

Comment: @Cfr Thank you for the list! What I would like to have is some prioritization. Like, study these three first as they are the most common.

Comment: Due to putting on hold I will repost it on Quora

Comment: @Alfa07 You could also post it to programmers.stackexchange.com, as already mentioned. I guess there will be more haskellers.